# Show that $V_{\mathbb{C}} \cong V \otimes \mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensor-products

I need to solve this example:

Let V be a $\mathbb{R}-$ vector space with $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} (V) = n$. Considering $\mathbb{C}$ as a $\mathbb{R}-$ vector space, we can define the tensor product between them as:

$$ V \otimes \mathbb{C} = \text{Span}({v \otimes \zeta : v \in V, \zeta \in \mathbb{C}}).$$

We define $\eta (v \otimes \zeta) := v \otimes (\eta \zeta)$, for $v \in V$ and for $\zeta, \eta \in \mathbb{C}$. By linearity, we can extend the product to all $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$, and we now obtain $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ as a $\mathbb{C}-$ vector space.

**Show that $V_{\mathbb{C}} \cong V \otimes \mathbb{C}$.**

The definition of the tensor product i'm using is the following:

Let $V$ and $W$ be two finite-dimensional vector spaces over the field $\mathbb F$. We define the tensor product between $V$ and $W$ as the set:

$$ V \otimes W  \,\,\colon = \{ \phi: V^* \times W^* \rightarrow  \mathbb F \,|\, \phi( \cdot , f) \in V^* \,\,\, \text{and} \,\,\,\phi(g, \cdot) \in W^* \,\, \forall g \in V^* , \,\, \forall f \in W^* .\}$$

Given $v \in V$ and $w \in W$, we denote as $v \otimes w$ the element of $V \otimes W$ defined as:

$$(v \otimes w) (g,f) := g(v)f(w), \forall (g,f) \in V^* \times W^* $$

and then, we can say that

$$ V \otimes W = Span( \{ v \otimes w : v \in V, w \in W \}) $$

I'm wondering if i can do this:

1- As $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ is the complexification of $V$, there exists a theorem that tells us $\text{dim}_{\mathbb{R}} (V) = \text{dim}_{\mathbb{C}}$ $(V_{\mathbb{C}})$ by proving that a $\mathbb{R}$ basis for $V$ is also a $\mathbb{C}$ basis for $V_{\mathbb{C}}$.

2- I want to construct a $\mathbb{C}$ basis for $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ that will show that the $\mathbb{C}$ dimension of $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ is also $n$, so the isomorphism is proved. The way of doing this is is in 3-:

3- The definition of the tensor product between two vector spaces over the same field give me a way to construct a basis for $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ as: $ (v \otimes \zeta)(g,f) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m} a_i b_j (v_i \otimes \zeta_j),$ with $a, b$ complex scalars (i guess). Since the $\mathbb{C}$ dimension of $\mathbb{C}$ over itself is $1$, we know that any complex number could be a basis for $\mathbb{C}$, so lets choose ${1}$ as a $\mathbb{C}$ basis for $\mathbb{C}$.

Then: $(v \otimes \zeta)(g,f) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i (v_i \otimes 1)$. As we have  $n$ elements on the $\mathbb{C}$-basis for $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$, the result is valid.

Is this sequence of arguments correct? If no, what could i do/improve?
Thanks

Comment: What is your definition of $V_\mathbb{C}$? It is normal to define $V_\mathbb{C}:= V\otimes \mathbb{C}$

Comment: I define $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ as $(V \times V, +V , \cdot V)$. With $+V$ being the usual sum of complex numbers and $\cdot V$ as $\mathbb{C} \times (V \times V) \rightarrow (V \times V)$; $(\alpha + i*\beta , (v_1, v_2)) \mapsto (\alpha v_1 - \beta v_2, \alpha v_2 + \beta v_1)$.

Comment: This post is a similar question, but I WANT to prove this constructing a basis for $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540747/show-that-v-otimes-mathbbr-mathbbc-is-isomorphic-to-v-iv?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I take it that the main question you are asking is how to construct a basis for $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$ as you have defined it.

Let $\{x_1, ..., x_n\}$ be a basis of $V$ and let $\{c_1, c_2\}$ be a basis of $\mathbb{C}$ over the reals. Then
$$\{x_i \otimes c_j : 1 \leq i \leq n, j = 1,2\}$$
is a basis of $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$.

**Linear independence**: suppose
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^2 \alpha_{ij}(x_i \otimes c_j) = 0$$
It is a fact that to every $x_i$ in the basis of $V$ there corresponds a linear functional $y_i$ which maps $x_i$ to 1 and every other basis vector to $0$. These $y_i$ form the *dual basis* to the $x_i$. Similarly, we obtain linear functionals $c'_1, c'_2$ which each map one basis vector of $\mathbb{C}$ to $1$ and the other to $0$. What is the value of our tensors on a pair of these linear functionals?
$$(x_i \otimes c_j)(y_g, c'_h) = y_g(x_i)c'_h(c_j)$$
By the way we have defined the $y$ and $c'$ functionals, if $i=g$ and $j=h$ the value is $y_g(x_g)c'_h(c_h) = 1$; otherwise, the value is $0$. Going back to the sum above, if we feed it $(y_g, c'_h)$ as arguments, every term will be $0$ except for the one containing the tensor $x_g \otimes c_h$. Thus:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^2 \alpha_{ij}(x_i \otimes c_j)(y_g, c'_h) = \alpha_{gh} = 0$$
This proves that all scalars $\alpha_{gh}$ (for $1 \leq g \leq n$ and $h = 1,2$) are 0, which suffices to prove linear independence.

**Span is the space** $V \otimes \mathbb{C}$: left to the reader.

By the way, this is a generic way to make a basis for $V \otimes W$ given bases for $V$ and $W$.
Hope this helps!